# How can I determine if a broadcast receiver was invoked when the app was running as opposed to when the app was dormant or in the background?

Tags: android

I have a BroadcatReceiver registered in the manifest for the purpose of silencing audio when the phone rings. I would like the BroadcastListener to behave differently in 3 situations:

1. If it was invoked while the user was using it.
2. If it was invoked while in the background after the home button was pressed.
3. If it was invoked while in the background after an exit request/ onBackButtonPressed().

I want this ability to discern, because I think the broadcast receiver automatically and in a hidden way starts a service which sends a notification. If the user receives this notification after explicitly leaving the app it is annoying.

Here are some of my attempts

```
  public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    //private final static Global global = Global.getInstance();
    private static final String TAG = MyBroadcastReceiver.class.getName();

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "broadcast recieved");
    //Log.d(TAG, "context package name is: " + context.getPackageName());

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.d(TAG, "State : " + state);

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) 
        {

            Log.d(TAG, "context package name: " + context.getPackageName());

            Global global = Global.getInstance();
            global.shutUp();

            Log.d(TAG, "global package name: " + global.getPackageName());

            String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.d(TAG, "Calling number: " + phoneNumber);





            //TODO try to condition this if receiver activated from outside the application 
            if(isAppOnForeground(context))
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "app is in forgeround");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "app is not in forgeround");
            }

            if(isMyServiceRunning(context))
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "service running");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "service isn't running");
            }


            //global.stopService(new Intent(ReturnService.class.getName()));
            //Log.d(TAG, "requested return service stoped");

        }
    }

    //I think this return is imperative so that return service isn't invoked 
    return;
}


private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) 
{
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    if (appProcesses == null) 
    {
      return false;
    }

    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();

    for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) 
    {
      if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) 
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }


private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context) 
{
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) 
    {
        if (ReturnService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: you say "app was dormant or in the background". What do you mean your app is, an activity, a service, or a combination of activities and services?

Comment: I mean that the user has hit the home button and is doing something else while the app is kept alive by the OS

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler solution in your case would be to simply set on a global flag when your launcher activity is created and off when it is destroyed. If your app is not open when a broadcast is sent to your receiver, that flag will be off and you can then operate accordingly.

Comment: I am trying to know if the broadcast receiver was called when the user was using the app or after he hit the home button and was doing something else.

Comment: You can detect if the back or home button were pressed and set the flag there. May I ask why do you need that functionality exactly?

Comment: Using your suggestion I would have to detect and set the flag from each activity's onBackPressed() only if it does not affect internal activity features like fragments etc and is the root activity for the entire app. Doing this for each activity is long and bug prone as well as creating duplicate code. I will try to edit my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

**If** your application is an activity, (and I do not think it is e.g. an InputMethodService) you can override the Activity methods *onPause()* and *onResume()*. If you set some *static* flag to true in one of them and clear it in the other, that flag will tell you whether the last activity is on the screen.

Comment: This is not always so because I will have to do this for all my activities since the home button will call on pause exactly as would the back button or ordinary navigation.

Comment: When you press the home button, the app goes to background. OTOH, if you leave one activity and navigate to another, it is possible to get onReceive() invoked between onPause() and onResume(). I'm not sure if it would be incorrect to consider an app in this transitional state as being in background.

Comment: Are you suggesting I implement onReceive() in all my activities and set a static flag there?

Comment: Activities get destroyed and created each time the user turns the screen, their life cycle matches the lifetime of the view hierarchy, but I do not think it matches the life cycle of your... whatever it is. Google docs suggest using a service. As to the flag, just `class MyActivity extends Activity { public static boolean isActive; void onResume(){isActive=true;} void onPause(){isActive=false;}` and all your activities may extend this class, there will be only one instance of the flag.